# Ubuntu freezes right after boot

Tags: boot, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my HP Envy 13, I had it running before on an external SSD and everything worked great (except for the speakers but that's a different story).

Now I installed it on the internal SSD as I was finally able to get rid of windows on my laptop, but it freezes completely, seconds after booting. Not even REISUB works.

The very weird thing though is that everything works perfectly when I connect an external display through my USB-C adapter and HDMI. A few seconds after disconnecting the display it freezes again. Also, it boots into recovery mode without problems.

Another point that might help is that 22.04 has the same problems, but 20.04 works without problems.